Getting errors from packages that are not installed
I'm getting the following error for a package not included in by Podfile when building my code using Xcode.

Binary target FirebaseAnalytics could not be mapped to an artifact with expected name FirebaseAnalytics


Binary target GoogleAppMeasurement could not be mapped to an artifact with expected name GoogleAppMeasurement

Can someone please help?
Here's my Podfile:
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '13.0'

target 'test' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Minuteapp
  pod 'SwiftMessages'
  pod 'GoogleSignIn'
  pod 'Promises' 
  pod 'Flurry-iOS-SDK/FlurryMessaging'
  pod ‘Flurry-iOS-SDK/FlurrySDK’
  pod 'ApphudSDK'
  pod 'FittedSheets'
  pod 'ColorThiefSwift'
  pod "SwiftChart"
  pod 'SDWebImage'
  pod 'AQPlayer'
  pod 'STPopup'
  pod 'Toast-Swift'
  pod 'PaddingLabel'
  pod 'GoogleSignIn'
  pod 'DeviceKit'
  # pod 'SwiftyStoreKit'
  pod 'ReachabilitySwift'
  pod 'Adjust'
  pod 'Amplitude'
  pod 'OneSignal/OneSignal', '>= 5.0.0', '< 6.0'
  pod 'OneSignal/OneSignalInAppMessages', '>= 5.0.0', '< 6.0'
  # If your app does not use CoreLocation, you can remove this:
  pod 'OneSignal/OneSignalLocation', '>= 5.0.0', '< 6.0'
end


post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH'] = 'YES'
    end
  end
    installer.generated_projects.each do |project|
          project.targets.each do |target|
              target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                  config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '13.0'
               end
          end
   end
end


Maybe  you include them as swift packages: Go to your project settings > Package Dependencies to check.
